# Vim region with keywords in syntax patterns

Tags: vim, syntax, vimscript

I need to create a custom vim region with determines classes and structs. The code, for example,

```
syn region myCxxClass start="\(class\|struct\)\_[ \t]\+" end="}[^;]*;" transparent
```

The patterns for start and end probably will be changed, but the problem is that this kind of region does not work, because `class` and `struct` are keywords.

How to work around this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right about the keyword match preventing a match of your new region. To workaround, you need to redefine the keywords to be contained in your region:

```
syn clear cStructure
syn clear cppStructure
syn keyword cStructure struct contained
syn keyword cppStructure class contained
syn region myCxxClass start="\(class\|struct\)\_[ \t]\+" end="}[^;]*;" contains=cStructure,cppStructure
```